# Import a table from oracle 11g to create ER diagram using ERWIN tool

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, erwin

I am trying to import the table from the oracle database into the Erwin tool in order to create the ER diagram. can anyone please let me know how i can do this???

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to reverse engineer the Oracle database (assuming you have a valid ERwin license.

In ERwin, go to tools / Reverse engineer / and then choose to reverse engineer directly to a database or a script, the DBMS Type and version you are connecting to.
The next dialog box with prompt you to specify what database object you need to get information from and the granularity of the properties of metadata for each object chosen.  There are other option to choose relating to owners, tablespace options as well as ability to infer primary key via index / names.
Finally, The next dialog box will prompt you to connect to your Oracle instance and depending on you rights to the object (schema), etc., Erwin will generate a new diagram for you in ERwin version R9, a Main Subject area stored display in R7 and R8 (this is the same as a diagram in R9).

If you are trying to just reverse engineer 1 or "n" number of tables it might be best to generate the script from Oracle and then use Erwin R/E (reverse engineer) using the script option.  Or try complete compare against a blank model.. This is another functionality and is more complex and should be treated as another subject matter for another discussion but I just wanted to make mention that this is a known practice.